# Banach space geometry without bounded operators?

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I understand that $B(X)$ can be think of as the collection of symmetries of a Banach space $X$, and that they provide important information concerning the geometric structure of the space. But I am just curious, how far can one go without $B(X)$?

Or in other words, what kinds of properties are *so intrinsic* to a space that can even be realised without thinking about the operators? I guess the notion of *symmetry*  should be implicit behind all kinds of geometry, but how implicit can they be?

This question is rather of *backwards* nature but still might be interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Completeness, compactness, separability, closedness and complementability of subspaces. What is your definition of symmetries?

Comment: @Norbert Yes. All these are *intrisic* properties of the underlying space. By symmetries of a space I refer to the endomorphisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometric properties can often be described as properties of $B(X)$ (or subspaces of it) or as properties on $X$. (Of course we only call them 'geometric' if we can describe them in $X$). Sometimes geometric properties were first observed as properties of operators. Let me give an example:

In 1964, if I'm not mistaken, Daugavet observed that on $C([0,1])$, every compact $T\in K(C[0,1])$ (denoting by $K(X)$ the space of compact operators on $X$) has maximal distance to the identity, that is we have 
\[ \|\mathrm{Id} + T\| = 1 + \| T\|, \quad T \in K(C[0,1]) \]
This property seems first to be a property of operators, but intrestingly, this property, which was afterwards called the Daugavet property, can be described geometrically. A space $X$ is said to be (a) Daugavet (space), if it shares this property. Now for the geometric description: The part of the unit ball $B_X$ which lies on one side of a hyperplane is called a slice, that is a slice a set (for $x^* \in S_{X^*}$ and $\epsilon > 0$)
\[ S(x^*,\epsilon) = \{x \in B_X \mid x^*(x) \ge 1 -\epsilon \} \]
A space is now exactly then Daugavet iff these slices have 'big' diameter, that is given a slice $S(x^*, \epsilon)$ an $y \in S_X$, and a $\delta > 0$, there is an $x \in S(x^*, \epsilon)$ with $\|x-y\| \ge 2 - \delta$.

Comment: When you are talking about $S_{X^*}$ you are already using functionals (operators into $\mathbb{C}$)

Comment: It seems very interesting. But can yo give some more details about the $S_X$? How is it defined? Thanks!

Comment: @Norbert Good point! But I guess we can restrict the definition of an operator to be one map from the space to itself, and see whether this gives us something interesting.

Comment: @Norbert You are right, but I think we can get rid of the functionals by defining a Hyperplane to be a 1-codimensional closed subspace $H$. Given such an $H$, which intersects $B_X$ and a $x \in X\setminus H$, we can define $S(H, x)$ as the $\{y \in B_X \mid \operatorname{conv}\{y,x\} \cap H = \emptyset\}$. So we can descibe a slice without using functionals.

Comment: @HuiYu $S_X$ denotes the unit sphere $\{x \in X \mid \|x\| = 1\}$.